# How to get the string value from a pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, tree, strtok

How do I get the string value from the `strtok` pointer and insert it in a tree?
Here's the input and division part:

```
printf("\nDigite a frase: ");
fgets(frase,TAM,stdin);

val=strtok(frase," (),.-;");
while(val!=NULL){      
   inserir(&raiz,val);
   val = strtok (NULL, " (),.-;");
}
```

And here is the insertion in the tree:

```
void inserir(no **arvore, char val[]){
    no *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*arvore))
    {
        temp = (no *)malloc(sizeof(no));
        temp->esq = temp->dir = NULL;
        temp->dado = val;
        temp->freq=1;
        *arvore = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*arvore)->dado)
    {
        inserir(&(*arvore)->esq, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*arvore)->dado)
    {
        inserir(&(*arvore)->dir, val);
    }
    else if(val==(*arvore)->dado){
        (*arvore)->freq++;
    }

}
```

I need the insertion part to compare the value of the string, but it's comparing the value of the pointer.

Comment: I believe you want to use strcmp

Comment: You will need to make a copy of the string when you insert it. Use `strdup()`perhaps, though it is  POSIX rather than Standard C.

Comment: `strdup()` is almost certainly going to be there. If not, you can `char* newStr = malloc(strlen(oldStr) + 1) ; strcpy(newStr, oldStr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @gbtimmon. I changed the compare method to:

```
int comp=strcmp(val, (*arvore)->dado);

if(comp<0)
{
    inserir(&(*arvore)->esq, val);
}
else if(comp>0)
{
    inserir(&(*arvore)->dir, val);
}
else if(comp==0){
    (*arvore)->freq++;
}
```